# I am getting an error in python code

Tags: python, numpy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\main_stereo.py", line 56, in <module>
    leftCh  = myconv(leftimp, waveData) # convolution of left ear impulse response and waveData
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Downloads\my_conv.py", line 34, in myconv
    z=[0]*len_h+x    
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40001) (128)
```

**My convolution is what is giving the trouble, it is giveing me the above error and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong**

mycon.py

```
import numpy as np
def  myconv(x,h):


# INPUT PARAMETERS---------------------------------------------------------
# x: input signal
# h: impulse response
```

here are the inputs to the function:

which I believe is an array

```
[  5.94000000e+02  -7.70000000e+02   9.75000000e+02  -1.17400000e+03
   1.32740000e+04   1.02210000e+04  -2.80010000e+04  -1.13600000e+03
   1.43450000e+04  -9.92000000e+02   3.42200000e+03   2.17110000e+04
   1.11780000e+04  -1.48470000e+04   2.62200000e+03   1.03150000e+04
   1.48400000e+03  -3.60800000e+03  -3.51100000e+03  -5.28700000e+03
  -1.33000000e+03   4.20000000e+02  -4.47000000e+03  -3.88100000e+03
  -3.54200000e+03  -8.05000000e+02  -1.83300000e+03  -1.08700000e+03
   9.00000000e+02  -2.83000000e+02  -1.31000000e+02  -9.43000000e+02
  -1.33000000e+03  -2.49000000e+03  -1.04400000e+03  -1.73100000e+03
  -1.56700000e+03  -1.36500000e+03  -2.01500000e+03  -1.20100000e+03
  -1.08500000e+03  -6.01000000e+02  -7.44000000e+02  -2.92000000e+02
  -9.61000000e+02  -9.57000000e+02  -8.16000000e+02  -7.85000000e+02
  -2.51000000e+02  -4.10000000e+01  -4.42000000e+02  -4.09000000e+02
  -1.54000000e+02   6.70000000e+01   1.70000000e+01  -3.55000000e+02
  -6.34000000e+02  -6.22000000e+02  -6.10000000e+02  -5.62000000e+02
  -2.04000000e+02  -3.24000000e+02  -2.85000000e+02  -4.50000000e+02
  -2.13000000e+02  -3.50000000e+01  -4.50000000e+01   7.50000000e+01
   7.10000000e+01  -1.02000000e+02  -1.84000000e+02  -2.09000000e+02
  -2.30000000e+02  -4.60000000e+01   9.80000000e+01  -7.30000000e+01
  -2.02000000e+02  -7.90000000e+01   4.00000000e+00   8.00000000e+00
   9.00000000e+00   6.60000000e+01  -6.40000000e+01  -5.40000000e+01
  -8.60000000e+01  -7.80000000e+01   5.30000000e+01   1.08000000e+02
   4.10000000e+01  -6.20000000e+01  -2.00000000e+02  -1.26000000e+02
  -2.00000000e+00   1.30000000e+02   1.93000000e+02   8.40000000e+01
  -1.20000000e+02  -2.74000000e+02  -9.30000000e+01   7.70000000e+01
   1.26000000e+02  -1.50000000e+01  -5.60000000e+01  -1.26000000e+02
  -1.17000000e+02   1.20000000e+01   7.20000000e+01   7.20000000e+01
  -4.20000000e+01  -1.14000000e+02  -1.22000000e+02   3.00000000e+00
   1.61000000e+02   2.00000000e+02   1.43000000e+02   5.30000000e+01
   5.00000000e+01   1.75000000e+02   2.10000000e+02   1.92000000e+02
   1.31000000e+02   9.20000000e+01   7.50000000e+01   1.20000000e+02
   1.87000000e+02   1.69000000e+02   1.15000000e+02   9.10000000e+01]
```

and this which is another array:

```
[-0.00985718 -0.00982666 -0.00912476 ...,  0.00064087  0.00015259
 -0.00061035]
```

Comment: FYI your first array you posted has 2 arrays...

Comment: sorry about that... fixed, however code still does not work

Comment: `[0]*len_h+x ` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to add [0,0,0,0,0,... before x

so say len_h was 10 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,x1,x2,....]

Comment: ???? Where's the question?

Comment: Ok can you split that operation into two? So you know where the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix `np.arrays()` and lists. Instead of `[0]*len_h+x` you should write `np.zeros(len_h) + np.asarray(x)`. To clarify:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]
np_a = np.array(a)

print(a+a)  # gives [1,2,3,1,2,3]
print(np_a + np_a) # gives[2,4,6] of type np.array()
```

Comment: I tried to implement what I think you were suggesting and it still gave me the same error

Comment: Could it be that you want to concatenate ``np.zeros(len_h)`` and ``np.asarray(x)``? Then you should write ``np.hstack([np.zeros(len_h), np.asarray(x)])``.